# Random symmetrical matrices for generalized eigenvalue problem - How to solve

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, generalized-eigenvector

Assume that we have $A$ and $B$ and they both are real symmetrical random matrices, e.g they have both negative and positive real values.

Now I want to solve $$AV = BVD$$ where $V$ are real eigenvectors and $D$ are real eigenvalues.

This is equivalent to the MATLAB command:

```
[V, D] = eig(A, B)
```

Is that possible to solve? What decomposition should I use here? 
I have looked up some tools from NetLib about solving generalized eigenvalue problem. But they only show that $B$ must have real positive symmetrical values. https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node54.html

So I assume that NetLib have no solution for my math problem.

Comment: I don't know about Netlib specifically, but you might note that when $B$ is not positive definite the generalized eigenvalues and eigenvectors may be complex.  For example, with $A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & -1}$ and $B = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0}$ the generalized eigenvalues are $1 \pm  i$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hmm...In this case, both A and B is random symmetrical. I can accept if the values become complex, because I have data that will not generate complex eigenvalues nor eigenvectors.